# Linear regression showing distance from points

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

Inspiring me from :

- this post : [Linear Regression in LaTeX using TikZ](https://latexdraw.com/linear-regression-in-latex-using-tikz/)
- and this post : [Pgf-Plot make a line between node and function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533961/pgf-plot-make-a-line-between-node-and-function)

I wanted to draw a linear regression on which lines represent the distance between a node and the regression function.

The code should behave as the two topics mentionned before, but I don't know how to write it. As the mix of the two technics seems to be never mentionned before in another topic, could anyone help me ?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%    xmin = 0, xmax = 11,
%    ymin = 0, ymax = 11,
    width = \textwidth,
    height = 0.75\textwidth,
    xtick distance = 1,
    ytick distance = 10,
    grid = both,
    minor tick num = 1,
    major grid style = {lightgray},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
    xlabel = {Expérience (en années)},
    ylabel = {Salaire (en k\euro)},
    legend cell align = {left},
    legend pos = north west
]
 
% Plot data
\addplot[teal, only marks] 
table[col sep=comma,x=YearsExperience, y=Salary] {Salary_Data.csv};
 
% Linear regression
\addplot[thick,orange] 
table[
    x = YearsExperience,
    y = {create col/linear regression={y=Salary}},col sep=comma
] {Salary_Data.csv};

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{f}{1}{\pgfmathparse{\pgfplotstableregressiona * #1 + \pgfplotstableregressionb}}

% Ecarts
\addplot[only marks, mark=*, mark size=1pt, mark options={draw=red, fill=red}] 
table[
    x = YearsExperience,
    y = f(x),
    col sep=comma
] {Salary_Data.csv};

% Add legend
\addlegendentry{Données brutes}
\addlegendentry{
    Régression linéaire : $ x =
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} t
    \pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$
};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

If you are interested in the data used for the example, you can find it here : [Salary_data.csv](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/ravitejakotharu/salary-datacsv)

Thank you !